# Entity Framework 6: método de remoção não funciona

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando excluir um objeto utilizando o *repository pattern*, mas o problema é que ao chamar o método para a remoção não acontece nada, nem lança exceção.

FinanceiroController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    var financa = _financeiroApp.ObterFinanca(id); // Aqui retorna o objeto sem nenhuma exceção.
    _financeiroApp.Remover(financa);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

RepositoryBase.cs:

```
public void Remover(T obj)
{
    banco.Set<T>().Remove(obj); // Não remove, mas também não lança nenhuma exceção.
    banco.SaveChanges();
}
```

Não consigo entender, pois ao obter o objeto ele fica dentro do contexto e, sendo assim, deveria ser removido sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Já tentou dar um `contexto.SaveChanges();` após remover o objeto?

Comment: Tentei sim Diego, tinha esquecido de colocar aqui. Já editei.

Comment: pode mostrar como está a declaração da sua Classe RepositoryBase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se seu objetivo é excluir, você pode altera o seu *Remove* por [DeleteObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.deleteobject.aspx)

ObjectContext.DeleteObject(entity) marca a entidade como excluídos no contexto. (EntityState é excluído depois disso.) Se você chamar SaveChanges depois o Entity Framework envia uma instrução SQL DELETE para o banco de dados. Se não há restrições de referência no banco de dados a entidade será excluído, caso contrário, uma exceção é lançada.

Seu [EntityCollection.Remove(childEntity)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337024(v=vs.110).aspx), marca **o relacionamento entre pai e filho Entity como eliminados**. Se o relacionamento tem uma restrição de integridade referencial, chamando o método Remove em um dependentes marcas objeto tanto o relacionamento e o objeto dependente para exclusão. Isto ocorre porque a restrição indica que o objecto dependente não pode existir sem um relacionamento ao pai.

Remover retorna falso quando o objeto especificado não está na coleção.

[Raferencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723626/entity-framework-remove-vs-deleteobject)